# Ionic2 Push notification plugin gives error on android build

Tags: ionic2

i am new to ionic after adding push notification plugin it gives the android sdk not found error.

> Error: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is
>   not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment
>   variable.

I set all the envoirnment variable as follows

[image: Environment variable]

Comment: what is the output for `cordova requirements`?

Comment: Are you sure this happened after you added push notification plugin? If yes, then try removing it and try building. See if that works?

Comment: yes i i am sure before adding the plugin it will build the project.

Comment: Try removing it now. And then see.